# initialize jQuery filter using Hash or GET-parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE**
Due to low activity on my original question (below) I rephrase it simply like this:
 
How can I initialize [**MIXITUP jQuery filter**](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com) from other url using Hash or GET-parameters?

====

I am using [**MIXITUP jQuery filter**](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com) for sorting several elements on one page. Is there a way to make a link from another page with one of the filers already active?
The idea is to have one link for each `category` and also one `main` link for the hole page. The category link would land the visitor on the second page with the `selected category` filter already activated. If the visitor would choose the `main` link he would land on the page with `all categories` visible.
For example lets say I sell cables and want to have a link from `index` to `store` with `HDMI` activated, so that when the jump has been made the visitor lands on the `store` page and only sees `HDMI` cables, with the option of selecting other filters to see the rest of the products of course.
Please ask if you need more information, sample code or anything else.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It has an API with methods such as `filter` …

Comment: You'll need to write that yourself. On the page check for a given Hash or GET-parameter and initialize your filter accordingly.

Comment: @schlingel,thank you. can you please elaborate.. maybe show me an example. How would it look if I'd like to jump with " data-filter='.category-1' " activated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the filter which will take effect right when the page is loaded by using the [`load.filter` setting](https://github.com/patrickkunka/mixitup/blob/master/docs/configuration-object.md#loadfilter) like this:

```
$('#container').mixItUp({
  load: {
    filter: 'your filter'
  }
});
```

Nothing stops you from getting the value for this setting from [`document.location.hash` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). You can check whether the hash is empty, and if it's not, use its value as a filter:

```
$('#container').mixItUp({
  load: {
    filter: document.location.hash == '' ? 'all' :
      ('.' + document.location.hash.substring(1))
  }
});
```

`hash.substring(1)` is needed because the string would include the `#` character itself, and I append `.` in the beginning because I think it's likely that you want to always filter by class and there's no need to include the dot in the URL.

Demo on CodePen:

- No filter: http://s.codepen.io/izstas/full/Ddkse
- Filter by class `category-1`: http://s.codepen.io/izstas/full/Ddkse#category-1

Comment: Absolutely fabulous!! Easy to understand, clear and polite answer! Thank you so much!! Please contact me on private chat

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Is there a way to show the hash when changing the active filter. So when another filter is chosen the url updates? ie: http://s.codepen.io/izstas/full/Ddkse#category-2 when you green category 2 is chosen?

Comment: Do you know about SEO disadvantages of this technique? Will this not cause duplicate pages?